# Replacing the elements that meet special condition in List with Python in a functional way

Tags: python, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I have a list `[1, 2, 3, -100, 2, -100]`.
I need to replace `-100` with `"ERROR"`, and others to their corresponding string.

I could code like this.

```
resList = []
for val in list:
    if val == -100:
        resList.append("ERROR")
    else:
        resList.append("%d" % val)
```

How can I do the same thing in a functional way.

I tried mapping.

```
resList = map(lambda w: if w == -100: "ERROR" else:("%d" % val), list)
```

However it doesn't compile as it has syntax error.
What's wrong with them?

Comment: Read the comments on Mark Byers' answer no matter which solution you choose; they explain your syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one doesn't work:

```
resList = map(lambda w: if w == -100: "ERROR" else:("%d" % val), list)
```

It fails because you can't have a block inside a lambda expression.

I prefer the [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) approach:

```
resList = ['ERROR' if item == -100 else item for item in yourlist]
```

This shouldn't generate any errors. If you are getting errors, it's because there are errors elsewhere in your program. Or perhaps the indentation is wrong. Post the specific error message you get.

Also, I'd advise you not to use the name `list` for local variables because it hides the builtin with the same name.

Comment: And with the lambda map, the equivalent is: map(lambda w: "Error" if w == -100 else w, yourlist), I think the list comprehension is more readable, though.

Comment: you can have a `... if ... else ... ` block inside `lambda` if you want. The real reason to not use map is because `map` is pretty ugly with unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
["ERROR" if -100 == val else str(val) for val in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

The map will work if you use the python ternary operator correctly and the "w" lambda parameter consistently.

```
map(lambda w: "ERROR" if w == -100 else ("%d" % w), list)
```

Comment: but that is still pretty ugly with unnecessary function calls. Also it's not Pythonic to do that and `"%d" % w`

Answer (score 0):

This code will do this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, -100, 2, -100]
resList = ['ERROR' if x == -100 else str(x) for x in list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some weird looking code, but it works:

```
resList = ["%s%s" % ("ERROR" * (val == -100), ("%d" % val) * (val != -100)) for val in list]
```

produces:

```
['1', '2', '3', 'ERROR', '2', 'ERROR']
```